# Filter out successful dependencies from AppInsight

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have created the following TelemetryFilter:

```
    public class TelemetryFilter : ITelemetryProcessor
    {
        private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }
        public TelemetryFilter(ITelemetryProcessor next)
        {
            Next = next;
        }
        public void Process(ITelemetry item)
        {
            var dependency = item as DependencyTelemetry;
            if (dependency != null && dependency.Success == true) return;
            Next.Process(item);
        }
    }
```

And added TelemetryFilter to TelemetruyProcessors in ApplicationInsights.config. It works when I run the application on my machine but when it is deployed to test and production environments, dependencies are getting collected by Azure AppInsights. When I see them in Azure Portal they have the property `Call status: true`. Is `Call status` refers to `dependency.Success`? What's the best way to filter out all successful calls to decrease our AppInsights data ingress and lower our Azure bill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `ApplicationInsights.config` file wasn't set to be copied into the output folder by the build process. That's why it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Filter out all successful dependencies:

you can initialize the filter in code. In a suitable initialization class,

AppStart in `Global.asax.cs`, insert your processor into the chain:

```
var builder = TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DefaultTelemetrySink.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder;

builder.Use((next) => new SuccessfulDependencyFilter(next));

// If you have more processors:

builder.Use((next) => new AnotherProcessor(next));

builder.Build();
```

Refer [for filtering sampling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#create-a-telemetry-processor-c)
& [for request filtering](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/request-filtering-in-application-insights-with-telemetry-processor/)

To Reduce Application Insights cost

You need to optimize Telemetry with Application Insights check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/may/devops-optimize-telemetry-with-application-insights)

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58056958/how-to-reduce-azure-application-insight-cost) for some more methods to reduce Application insights cost